# nix-shell with R interpretter and submodules

Tags: r, nix, nixos

Can I use R, with required submodules (e.g., ggplot2) with nix-shell?

For example, using Python with submodules:

```
nix-shell -p python34 python34Packages.pandas
```

However, I can't seem to see how to do the equivalent with R.

```
nix-shell -p R
```

Gives me a vanilla R, but what about submodules? I'm not sure I know enough about using nix-shell to evaluate nix expressions, but could [this](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/7475728593a49f09c4b7b959b15513aee38ab4b4/pkgs/development/r-modules/README.md) be used from nix-shell as a command?

*Note: It is my preference **not** to pop the expression from the above link in a `shell.nix` or `default.nix`. Rather as a single command.*

Comment: What is wrong with `nix-shell -p R rPackages.dplyr rPackages.ggplot2`?

Comment: @Alex much simpler. I saw the linked documents and assumed that wouldn't work. Could you pop that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same approach as in your Python example:

```
nix-shell -p R rPackages.dplyr rPackages.ggplot2
```

Comment: Great, thanks very much. The documentation using rWrapper had me a little confused.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a nix expression to `nix-shell` using the `-E` flag. So the following is valid:

```
nix-shell -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; rWrapper.override {packages = with rPackages; [ggplot2 reshape2];}'
```

Comment: We really need to improve the nix CLI. While the above solves the problem, it is a WAY too complex.

Comment: It is, but I'm also doing something a bit more complicated than the usual. Normally you'd use a `shell.nix` file, but I was launching directly to use as a replacement/wrapper to calling `R` command in Emacs' org-mode babel.